# Pandas str-methods not working: AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_upper'

Tags: python, pandas, series

I´m trying to get familiar with the pandas package. As I'm trying to manipulate strings in a column I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Udemy/pandas/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(df["name"].str.upper())
  File "C:\Users\saxal\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saxal\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 2686, in upper
    result = self._array._str_upper()
AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_upper'
```

I already tried installing different versions of numpy and pandas without success. Currently installed `pandas 1.2.0` and `numpy 1.19.5`

If I run the exact same code e. g. on repl.it it works perfectly fine.

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ["first name", "second name", "third name"]
numbers = [1,2,3]
data = {
    "name": names,
    "number": numbers
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df["name"].str.upper())
```

Comment: Your code works on my computer.

Comment: In a different environment it also works for me. That's what confuses me the most.